# Worklight Application Center - Active Directory integration

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-appcenter

I'm trying to integrate IBM Worklight Application Center with AD.
It's deployed on Websphere Liberty Profile on Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise VM.
I'm using documentation from this link: [IBM Knowledgebase](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.installconfig.doc/appcenter/t_ac_lib_ldap.html)

I managed to connect with AD for authentication purposes with this config in server.xml:

```
<ldapRegistry id="ldap" realm="SampleLdapADRealm" 
                host="ad.btb.hr" port="389" ignoreCase="true" 
                baseDN="ou=BTB,dc=btb,dc=hr" 
                bindDN="<myBindDN>" 
                bindPassword="<myBindPW>"
                ldapType="Microsoft Active Directory" 
                sslEnabled="false"> 
    <activedFilters userFilter="(&amp;(sAMAccountName=%v)(objectClass=user))"
                    groupFilter="(&amp;(cn=%v)(objectcategory=group))" 
                    userIdMap="user:sAMAccountName" 
                    groupIdMap="*:cn" 
                    groupMemberIdMap="memberOf:member">
    </activedFilters>
    <contextPool enabled="true" initialSize="1" maxSize="0" timeout="0s" waitTime="3000ms" preferredSize="3"/>
    <ldapCache>
        <attributesCache size="4000" timeout="1200s" enabled="true" sizeLimit="2000"/>
        <searchResultsCache size="2000" timeout="600s" enabled="true" resultsSizeLimit="1000"/>
    </ldapCache>
</ldapRegistry>

<!-- Begin of configuration added by IBM Worklight installer. -->

<!-- Declare the IBM Application Center Console application. -->
<application id="appcenterconsole" name="appcenterconsole" location="appcenterconsole.war" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="appcenteradmin">
            <group name="worklight-administrators"/>
        </security-role>
        <security-role name="appcenteruser">
            <group name="worklight-users"/>
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
</application>

<!-- Declare the IBM Application Center Services application. -->
<application id="applicationcenter" name="applicationcenter" location="applicationcenter.war" type="war">
    <application-bnd>
        <security-role name="appcenteradmin">
            <!-- <group name="appcentergroup"/> -->
            <group name="worklight-administrators"/>
        </security-role>
        <security-role name="appcenteruser">
            <group name="worklight-users"/>
        </security-role>
    </application-bnd>
    <classloader delegation="parentLast">
        <commonLibrary>
            <fileset dir="${wlp.install.dir}/lib" includes="com.ibm.ws.crypto.passwordutil_1.0.1.jar"/>
        </commonLibrary>
    </classloader>
</application>
```

Then I tried configuring ACL so I can pull in users and groups into "User and Group Management" part of App Center using this configuration:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.active" value="true"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.connectionURL" value="ldap://ad.btb.hr"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.user.loginName" value="sAMAccountName"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.security.binddn" value="<myBindDN>"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.security.bindpwd" value="<myBindPW>"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.user.base" value="ou=BTB,dc=btb,dc=hr"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.group.base" value="ou=BTB,dc=btb,dc=hr"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.user.displayName" value="displayName"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.group.name" value="cn"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.group.uniquemember" value="member"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.user.groupmembership" value="memberOf"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.cache.expiration.seconds" value="43200"/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.user.filter" value='"(&amp;(sAMAccountName=%v)(objectClass=user))"'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.group.filter" value='"(&amp;(cn=%v)(objectcategory=group))"'/>
```

Now, I'm getting this error when accessing Users/Groups link in App Center:

> [24.10.14. 09:14:24:379 CEST] 0000001b com.ibm.puremeap.services.MobileServices                     E {
>           "id": "5b5c3b4c-cb1d-4094-8e84-b1fee1b31b35",
>           "message": "FWLAC0004E: The LDAP server cannot be accessed.",
>           "productVersion": "6.2.0.00-20140613-0730"
>   }

What have I missed?

Answer (score 0):

You are using a very old version of Worklight 6.2; update your setup to use the latest.
You can get the latest Worklight Studio from Eclipse > Help > Eclipse Marketplace. For server artifacts, visit the IBM Fix Central website.

Additionally, the above contains a fix for a bug that may be yours.
PI24446 CONNECTING TO APPCENTER WITH A LOG-IN NAME DIFFERENT BY CASE SENSETIVE FROM THE LOG IN NAME DEFINED IN LDAP RESULT IN ERROR

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into it - It's a standalone server so I'll visit thm Fix Central website...

Answer (score 0):

The JNDI entry ibm.appcenter.ldap.user.displayName.filter is missing.
Try by setting it.

Comment: I added filter for displayName and now the error doesn't show but I still don't see LDAP users and groups listed in the Users/Groups Management Page :(

Comment: In this case you need to trace the LDAP requests (you can use a network protocol analayzer like Wireshark for example or get the trace report on the LDAP server).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue fixed by adding/modifying these two lines.

In my case it's `uid` not `sAMAccountName`

`jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.user.loginName" value="uid"`

`jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.user.filter" value='"(&amp;(sAMAccountName=%v)(objectClass=person))"'`

I used "person" as object class since the same mentioned in my LDAP registry configuration.

`jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.user.displayName.filter" value='"(&amp;(cn=%v)(objectclass=person))"'`

Group filter should be correct as I am using `Objectcategory=group`

`jndiEntry jndiName="ibm.appcenter.ldap.group.filter" value='"(&amp;(cn=%v)(objectcategory=group))"'/>`

All LDAP related info can be verified from AD server.